# Dynamically change BungeeCord server configuration

Tags: java, minecraft, bungeecord

I'm setting up a new Minecraft Server and I want to change my sub-servers using my own Plugin.

This doesnt work

```java
getProxy().getServers().put("game25568", new ServerInfo());
```

How can I add a server with a custom address and motd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want :)

https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/registering-server.51340/#post-576590

`By Spawl - on SpigotMC`

```
ServerInfo info = ProxyServer.getInstance().constructServerInfo(id, InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved(ip, port), "motd here", restricted);
ProxyServer.getInstance().getServers().put(id, info);
```